# How can I implement Apollo Server Federation with Kong API Gateway

Tags: apollo-server, kong, apollo-federation

I've done a lot of google searching + searching here in SO, but I still haven't found a concrete answer to this question. One person had the same question I did over on the Apollo forums but the question was never answered.

I understand how Apollo clients can extend models in different services through Apollo's federated schema, and an Apollo Server API Gateway automatically does the schema stitching. My question is, is it possible to implement Apollo Server on other API gateways like Kong API gateway, Apigee, etc? And if it is possible, how can I go about integrating Apollo server with Kong API Gateway? There is a github repository that does this but the repository is 2 years old, which means it won't have the latest versions of the Kong gateway nor Apollo server.